# How do you point to non-default php version without sudo in terminal

Tags: shell, symlink, php

Problem: When I ssh to my web server and run anything with "php", it runs an old php 5.2 for some reason. The link `/usr/bin/php` points to the wrong version. I cannot change this symlink.

What I tried: From folder `~/test` I'd like to install something, but it requires php 5.6. So I created a symlink in folder `~/tes` which points to php5.6:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/php56 php
```

To make sure the system checks the current directory for php, I've changed `PATH` variable and added current directory first:

```
PATH=/home/test:$PATH
```

No luck though.

Comment: Are you running it from a web page?  If so, what is your web server?

Comment: @JuliePelletier, from a terminal, ssh

Comment: @drewbenn it just calls `php`

Comment: export PATH=/home/test:$PATH

Answer (score 2):

You have provided the wrong directory in `PATH` declaration.

You have set the link in `~/test/` directory but in `PATH` declaration you have used `/home/test`.

Assuming you username is `foobar`, you need:

```
export PATH=/home/foobar/test:"$PATH"
```

Or just:

```
export PATH=~/test:"$PATH"
```

Or:

```
export PATH="$HOME"/test:"$PATH"
```

`export` is to make the changed `PATH` available to all child processes.

Comment: I've properly exported the path as suggested, which is confirmed when I `echo $PATH`. But when I type `which php` it points to the symlink in `/usr/bin/php` and so `php -v` still prints `php 5.2`. Maybe there's some environment variable I'm not aware of?

Comment: @vega Thats not possible, if you made the symlink properly and put the directory in the `PATH` at first it will be treated first. On a different note, you probably have 'alternatives` installed but that is a different matter. What happens when you use the link directly by full path?

Comment: Interesting, when I try full path `~/test/php -v` I get `Permission denied`, which explains why it defaults to the other symlink. Why denied? I just created it.

Comment: @vega check the permission of `/usr/bin/php56`

Comment: permission is `-rwxr-xr-x`. But if I run `/usr/bin/php56 -v`, it works, no permission warning. So why would it not work through the symlink?

Comment: @vega Whats the output of `readlink -f ~/test/php`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44161/discussion-between-vega-and-heemayl).